# Mapserver - dynamic contrast stretching for custom COLORRANGE's

Tags: raster, mapserver, stretch

In MapServer, is there a way to use the PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO" directive to get dynamic (current extent) contrast stretching with custom colorranges? When I test my mapfile (relevant layer part below) with the Openlayers viewer it gets the desired color ramps but does not do contrast stretching for the current extent. If I take the CLASS'es out the greyscale output is contrast stretched according to current extent. I have tried taking out the EXPRESSIONS and/or the DATARANGES but then it only takes the first COLORRANGE and does not stretch it.

```
# raster layer
LAYER  
    NAME "mapservtest"  
    TYPE RASTER  
    PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"  
    STATUS ON  
    DEBUG ON  
    PROJECTION  
        "init=epsg:3857"  
    END  
    METADATA  
        #WMS stuff here  
    END  
    TILEITEM "location" #location is a column in postgis table with varchar of the filepath to each image  
    TILEINDEX "index"  
    FILTER (`[datetime]` = `2015-01-01T00:00:00Z`)  
    OFFSITE 0 0 0  
    CLASS  
        EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 25 AND [pixel] < 30)  
        STYLE  
            COLORRANGE  "#00ff00"  "#0000ff"  
            DATARANGE 25 30  
        END # STYLE  
    END # CLASS  
    CLASS  
        EXPRESSION ([pixel] < 25)  
        STYLE  
            COLORRANGE  "#ff0000"  "#00ff00"  
            DATARANGE 20 25  
        END # STYLE  
    END # CLASS  
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the answer is no, but it may be possible to use dynamic scaling and classification together soon. See the ticket https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/5830#issuecomment-516913638 for details.

Perhaps you can get more pressure to include this enhancement into version 7.6 by adding a comment and volunteering to test.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that.